# Animating underline link with 3 different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, underline

I try to animate my links on hover event with 3 different colors, but I'm getting stuck on how to proceed.
I tried with linear-gradient property but it looks like it's not possible to animate it (?)

Here's an exemple below of what I'm trying to do, with a single color.

```js
var link = document.querySelector(".dropdown-item");

['mouseover', 'touchstart'].forEach(function (e) {
 link.addEventListener(e, function () {
  link.classList.add("is-active");
 });
});
 
['mouseleave', 'touchleave'].forEach(function (e) {
 link.addEventListener(e, function () {
  link.classList.remove("is-active");
 })
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-item::after {
 content: '';
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 2px;
 width: 0;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -10px;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 display: block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.is-active.dropdown-item::after {
 width: 100%;
 background: #123456;
 transition: width 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's what I'd like to do, with the same transition effect:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbxV5.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider gradient and multiple background:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(red, red), 
    linear-gradient(blue, blue), 
    linear-gradient(green, green);
  background-size: 0 10px;
  background-position: bottom left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-size: 
    33%  10px, 
    66%  10px, 
    100% 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is another way to do:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right, red 33%,green 33%,green 66%,blue 0);
  background-size: 0 10px;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-size: 100% 10px; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is it possible to do the same thing, with the line extending from the middle?